Package installation into a module
I have created a module to handle authentication, this module will contain Laravel Breeze package.
I tried specifying the path to the module during installation (using php artisan breeze:install "path-to-module") but it kept installing breeze in the main project.
How can I install it into the authentication module instead of main project?

To install Breeze into a specific module directory, you can follow these steps:

First, make sure your authentication module is set up correctly and is structured as a seperate directory within your laravel project.
Navigate to your laravel project directory in the terminal.
Use composer to require laravel breeze within your authentication module directory. you can do this by specifying the path to your module's composer.json file:

composer require laravel/breeze --working-dir=path/to/module # replace path/to/module with the actual path to your authentication module directory.


After running the composer command, laravel breeze should be installed within your authentication module directory, rather than in the main project directory.
this approach should allow you to keep your authentication module separate from the main project and install laravel breeze specifically into that module.


I did this but still can't get breeze installed in the module.
